# Not able to connect Sony NEX 5T to iPhone via Sony Camera API

Tags: android, ios, camera, sony, sony-camera-api

I am developing an iPhone and an Android app which will  connect to the Sony Camera NEX 5T via the Sony Camera API and receive an image being sent from the camera. I downloaded the Sony tutorial from https://developer.sony.com/2013/11/29/how-to-develop-an-app-using-the-camera-remote-api-2/ and tried using it.

I am not able to connect to the camera via the demo app as well as it doesnt locate my camera at all.
But if i use, play memories app by Sony, it locates and sends the image in a fraction on a second. I even tried to manually reach the camera via 10.0.0.1/sony/camera but it doesnt connect.

Any help will be greatly appreciated. A working demo from anyone would be highly helpful.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest a few things to check your setup.

1) Update to latest firmware on the camera (esupport.sony.com)

2) Smart Remote Control app in the NEX-5T camera (latest version is installed?)
https://www.playmemoriescameraapps.com/portal/usbdetail.php?eid=IS9104-NPIA09014_00-F00002

3) Latest version of iOS/Android sample applications from Camera Remote API SDK.

4) Start Smart Remote Control app in NEX-5T.

Best regards,
Prem, Member of Developer World team at Sony

Comment: Hi prem.. Is it not possible to directly fetch an image from the camera like the Sony Play memories app does? If yes, can you please outline that as i just want to receive an image from the camera into my app.

Comment: You can use 'setPostviewImageSize' to receive image of desired size. The camera will provide the URL of postview image in the response to 'actTakePicture'. This information and more description is available in the API Reference document. Best Regards, Prem, Member of Developer World team at Sony